# How to deal with 2 python.exe

Tags: python

In my computer I have 2 python scripts and its really troublesome because there is 2 path, it  makes me confuse when I want to put the path for task scheduler.do I have to delete other python?if so how to choose the one that i must delete?
actually for task scheduler I have been trying 2 python to access,but it always failed.I think one of the reason bcs there is 2 python

[image: python.exe]

Comment: Use the full path to python2 binary in the scheduler

Answer (score 0):

First one is the python interpreter for python 3.6 and another comes with Ananconda 3. SO you should use the fist one, by executing `where python` check which one has got preceedence.